# Copy document is saved but original not changes status using lotusscript

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, lotus

I have two document which is original and copy document. When I save copy, original will changes status too.

Follow up by my other question [Save copy document and change status field for copy document and original document using lotusscript button](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55915771/9688943). Below are my code.

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)
    Dim session As New NotesSession
    Dim db As NotesDatabase 
    Dim workspace As New NotesUIWorkspace
    Dim uidoc As NotesUIDocument
    Dim doc As NotesDocument
    Dim activeDoc As NotesDocument
    Dim view As NotesView
    Dim keys(1) As String

    '// Set database and doc
    Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
    Set uidoc = workspace.CurrentDocument
    Set doc = uidoc.Document    

    keys(0) = doc.PTagNo(0)
    keys(1) = "Lock"
    Set view = db.GetView("Computer")
    vpswd = Inputbox$("Pls input code to save :")

    If vpswd = "o" Then

        Set activeDoc= view.GetDocumentByKey(keys, True)
        If Not activeDoc Is Nothing Then
            If activeDoc.PStatus(0) = "Lock" Then
                activeDoc.DocumetId = doc.UniversalID
                Call activeDoc.ReplaceItemValue("PStatus", "Inactive")
                Call activeDoc.Save(True, False)
            End If
        End If
        Call uidoc.FieldSetText("PStatus" , "Active")
        Call uidoc.FieldSetText("SaveOptions" , "1")
        Call uidoc.Save
        Call uidoc.Close
    Else
        Msgbox "Wrong Code"
        Exit Sub
    End If  
End Sub
```

I already set variable and successfull saved. When I saved, Copy document is saved and change status to Active, but for Current document which currently with "Lock" status, did not change to "Inactive" status. Can anyone help me? Is there any error that I have made inside coding? Your help really appreciate. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this question. For my problem, I do not set TagNo as my first column. So I need to created new view with two column which is TagNo and Status. Set both column as ascending.